# How to Install "not installable" dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm trying to install Codelite on Ubuntu Artful (17.10). I've seen this problem is very common online but I haven't found a fix. Basically when I run `sudo apt-get install codelite wxcrafter` I get these unmet dependencies

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codelite : Depends: libclang1-3.6 (>= 3.2) but it is not installable
            Depends: libhunspell-1.3-0 (>= 1.3.3) but it is not installable
            Depends: liblldb-3.6 but it is not installable
            Recommends: lldb (>= 3.4) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Now I've tried to manually install Artful versions of the dependencies (such as [libclang1-3.9](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/libclang1-3.9)) but the error remains there. I'm kind of a noob on these sort of things. Is there anyway to like manually install a dependency? (from like a downloaded file?) Or is there any sort of fix to this?

Thank you very much!

Edit: I don't think it's the same as the the question this is marked as duplicate: that's about clashing dependencies this is about missing ones!

Comment: What happens if you try `sudo apt install nodejs` and then `sudo apt  install lldb` and then `sudo apt install liblldb-3.8` and then `sudo apt install libhunspell-1.6-0` and finally `sudo apt install libclang1-3.8`? In cases like this, try to install each dependency package manually and if it fails it will tell you why and that will tell you why when installing the original one it could not install dependencies automatically.

Comment: @marko same problem! Except the nodejs line, which is now installed. All the commands you gave me worked though and installed! So not sure if the version clash or something

Comment: Have you previously added any repositories to your sources? `wxcrafter` is not an Ubuntu package as far as I know, so presumably you added some PPA to get it? I don't have any dependency errors when I try installing the `codelite` package on 17.10, so perhaps mixing repositories is causing version clashes. Did you find the post linked by karel any help?

Comment: I did add some repositories as explained in http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/Repositories . Unfortunately the link karel gave is a different issue, as the guy has a conflict while I have missing dependancies. Not sure why they ended up marking as a duplicate as that's a different issue (with a different solution) as far as I know. I mean I don't know how to apply that solution to my problem, I don't have any conflicts...?

Comment: Which of the answers in the duplicate did you try and what were the results?  Simply stating "It's not a duplicate" doesn't help us help you... **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: It's simply a different issue. The accepted answer in the duplicate resolves the conflict but I have no conflicts...I just have uninstallable dependencies!